# Generic factory method to return specific object based on type

Tags: c#, oop, generics, switch-statement, factory-pattern

I Have the following base class :

```
public abstract class ItemComponentSaver<TType> : where TType : ItemComponent
{
    public abstract bool SaveItem(TType item, object objectRowInTableFromEF, PropertyInfo columnTypeProperty);
}
```

This one, also has some children, for each of the types that I support. My idea is to use them polymorphically to perform a save operation later on, for example

```
    public class CellSaver : ItemComponentSaver<Cell>
    {
        public override bool SaveItem(Cell item, object objectRowInTableFromEF, PropertyInfo columnTypeProperty)
        {
                // code here
        }
    }
```

Now, I know that at some point I need to create this stuff, so there's the unavoidable "switch" like statement, I craeted a factory for this:

```
public static class ItemComponentSaverFactory
{
    public static ItemComponentSaver<T> GetSaver<T>(ItemComponent entity) where T : ItemComponent
    {
        if (entity is Cell)
            return (ItemComponentSaver<T>)new CellSaver();

        if (entity is Row)
            return (ItemComponentSaver<T>)new RowSaver();
    }

}
```

The problem is, I can't cast the CellSaver to the return type, because it's generic. I could also return an interface instead of the class tpe, but of course, if I create the interface, I need to make it generic as well, because the return type is like that
How can I handle this case in an elegant way??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are other option for this design,but since we dont know the internals of what you are trying to do my answer will be based only with the presented code.
You can rewrite your GetSaver method like this:

```
     public static ItemComponentSaver<T> GetSaver<T>() where T : ItemComponent
     {
         if (typeof(T) == typeof(Cell))
             return new CellSaver() as ItemComponentSaver<T>;
         else if (typeof(T) == typeof(Row))
             return new RowSaver() as ItemComponentSaver<T>;
         else
             return null;//here you can return what u need in case no types match.
     }
```

Calling like so...

```
ItemComponentSaver<Row> saver = ItemComponentSaverFactory.GetSaver<Row>();
```

Comment: hi terry, thanks for your answer, I don't know how I didn't try that one out. By the way, I'd like to know which other good options for design would be good, at least from a "philosophical" point of view, they may adapt to my current code, it's always good to learn

Answer (score 1):

I think `ItemComponent` should have an abstract `SaveItem` function, and then `Cell` and `Row` should implement the `SaveItem` function.

All `ItemComponentSaver<TType>` would need to do is call `item.SaveItem`. No need for individual `CellSaver` and `RowSaver` classes at all.

Edit: in fact, unless you do more stuff outside `SaveItem`, I don't see the need for an `ItemComponentSaver<TType>` at all. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: thanks David, this was my initial approach, however, since the whole saving process uses in the end some DAL classes, I can't access them directly from the domain model (cell, row), and that's why I went with the "saver class" approach, which would be in the end a collaborator for this purpose.